# Xcode text not changing color when syntax is correct

Tags: xcode

I have one xcode project that for some reason, if the syntax is correct the color of the text isn't changed accordingly. The only text that is colored are words like int, BOOL, double, self, return, etc. Parameters like image->height or object types like UIImage or methods like initWithString are not being colored like they normally are. I've googled this problem but can only find out how to change the overall appearance under Preferences. I've compared the settings between this problematic project and others but have not been able to identify the issue. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem as you Kevin - can you answer your own question here and let us know how you solved the issue :)

Comment: Haha. I would if I was able to solve it. Still haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

If this only happens with one specific Xcode project, your project file might be corrupt.

Is it a big project?  Would it be troublesome to rebuild it from scratch?